# How can you view iPhone Safari serviceworker console.log messages?

Tags: service-worker

How can you view iPhone Safari ServiceWorker console.log messages?  I see how to view Mac Safari ServiceWorker console.log messages, but I don't see how to view the iPhone Safari ServiceWorker console.log messages

I have my iPhone connected to my Mac... On the Mac in Safari in the Develop menu item, I have two relevant items:

iPhone -> [my website] -> (gives lots options including the iPhone's console.logs but not the iPhone's ServiceWorkers' console.logs

Service Workers -> This gives options for the Mac's ServiceWorkers, but not the iPhones

Comment: Don't you see them because you can't open the browser console on iOS?

Comment: I updated my question... I can see the IOS browser console, but not the IOS serviceworker console